# how to add to a file, rather than overwrite using write.csv

Tags: r, csv

simple question - I am using the write.csv function in R:

```
write.csv(t(y), file = "test.csv")
```

Where y is a dataframe of a file in my directory

However, I have many files in my directory, and I want the output of each file to be written to "test.csv" by using a loop. However, just testing this out I notice that if I write to test.csv, and then repeat the command with another file, instead of adding it overwrites test.csv instead of adding to it.

so my question is how to I add to test.csv rather than overwrite it.

Thanks very much.

Comment: Help file of write.csv will show you that there is an argument append=TRUE for this function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
write.csv(t(y), file = "test.csv", append=TRUE)
```

should do it.